# Is it possible to calculate the random factor $r$ from a encrypted message and the private key in a Paillier cryptosystem?

Tags: public-key, randomness, paillier

I have already done my research and found various sources that state that it is possible but there are also a lot of them that says it is not possible to recover $r$. [This Q/A on this site](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64343/how-to-calculate-random-factor-in-paillier-cryptosystem) for example even states the formula to get it. I don't know if it is wrong or I am missing something since I was not able to make a working implementation of it.

Some friends told me it is impossible to get $r$ back since it was raised during encryption to the $n$-th power and ended up in a smaller subgroup which results in a loss of information that renders it unable to be recovered.

I asked on reddit and got told the following:

*$r$ is choosen to be between 0 and $n^2$. The plaintext can be between $0$ and $n$. The Ciphertext is however also between $0$ and $n^2$. Since the plaintext is fully preserved, the same is impossible for the randomness, as this would otherwise violate the theorem that lossless compression is impossible.*

I would like to know whether it is possible to calculate $r$ and how it is computed given that I have:

- $C \to$ ciphertext
- $P \to$ plaintext
- $N \to$ public key modulo $(p\cdot q)$

Also if it is not possible for all $r$ values to be recovered I would like to know if it would be possible to recover $r$ values smaller than $m$ bits (I know that reducing $r$ bit length makes the encryption less secure)

Answer (score 2):

It is strange that Wikipedia propose to choose $r\mod N^2$ while $r^N\mod N^2$ depends on $r\mod N$ only:
$$(r+tN)^N=r^N+r^{N-1}tN^2+\ldots\equiv r^N\pmod{ N^2}.$$ It means that you can recover only $r\mod N.$ In order to do it you can use the formula from the cited [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/64344/24046)
$$r\equiv (r^N)^M\pmod{ N}, $$
where $M = N^{-1}\bmod \phi(N)$.

Comment: So I have:

  $p = 56039$, 

  $q = 58727$,

  $n =  p·q = 3291002353$,

  $n^2 = 10830696487451536609$,

  $\phi(n) = (p-1)·(q-1) = 3290887588$,

ciphertext $c$ of $m = 12$ using $r = 7$ $\to c = 6859599884662874753$
I do

$P = decrypt(c) = 12$,
$c' = c·(1-P·n)\>mod\>n^{2} = 685959988466287475 · (1-12·3291002353)\> mod\> 10830696487451536609 = 2421846566699018322,$
$M = n^{-1}\> mod \>\phi(n) = 3291002353^{-1}\> mod\> 3290887588 = 1169309581,$
$r = c'^M \>mod\> n = 2421846566699018322^{1169309581}\> mod \>3291002353 = 2648362593$

which is not $12$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Kranga My calculations give $c=5368334944199256653$, $c'=4487862507998304930$ and $(c′)^M\mod n=7.$ Also here $c'=r^n\mod n^2$.